# Let to button a text of a textbox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a webbrowser, but i've problem with tkinter, this is the code but it give me an error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Fulvio\Desktop\OpenBrowser.py", line 10, in callback
  b=b+x+"&oq="+x+"&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.131037.133187.0.133344.13.9.1.3.3.0.195.895.0j6.6.0....0...1c.1.52.serp..3.10.922.ssgKbcBrPr0"
  NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

This is the code:

```
import webbrowser

from Tkinter import *

def retrieve_input():
    global x
    x = self.myText_Box.get("0.0", 'END-1c')

def callback():
    b = "https://www.google.it/search?q="
    b=b+x+"&oq="+x+"&gs_l=serp.3..0l10.131037.133187.0.133344.13.9.1.3.3.0.195.895.0j6.6.0....0...1c.1.52.serp..3.10.922.ssgKbcBrPr0"

    if self.myText_Box.get("0.0", END)=="text":
        webbrowser.open(b)

top = Tk()

myText_Box = Label(top, text="Cerca")

myText_Box.grid(row=0, column=0)

E1 = Entry(top, bd = 5)

E1.grid(row=0, column=1)

MyButton1 = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=callback)

MyButton1.grid(row=1, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```

Sorry if the code isn't in div grey but i don't know how do it

Comment: global x in callback() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Repair assignment syntax for **`b`** in **`callback`**

Moving into a Class will enable you to work with class-instance-variable without resorting to **`global x`**

Avoid `global`-s unless a very special need indeed requires 'em

```
from Tkinter import *                        # just re-shaped into a Class-mode
import webbrowser                            # no app.logic revisions here

class aTkGuiApplication():
    def __init__( self, master ):            # .INIT auto-exec'd method to setup <self>
        root            = master
        self.x          = 'init'             # .DEF <self>.x instance-variable
        self.myText_Box = Label(  root, ...  # .DEF <self>.myText_Box instance
        self.E1         = Entry(  root,
                                  bd = 5
                                  )
        self.MyButton1  = Button( root,
                                  text    = "Submit",
                                  width   = 10,
                                  command = callback
                                  )
        self.E1.grid(             row = 0, column = 1 )
        self.myText_Box.grid(     row = 0, column = 0 )
        self.MyButton1.grid(      row = 1, column = 1 )

    def callback( self ):                            # .GUI Event-<control-loop>
        self.b = "https://www.google.it/search?q="   # .SET <self>.b
        self.b = self.b + self.x + "&og=" + self.x + "...etc...etc..."

        if self.myText_Box.get( "0.0", END ) == "text":
            webbrowser.open( self.b )

    def retrieve_input():                               # Erratum: 
        self.x = self.myText_Box.get( "0.0", 'END-1c' ) # .SET <self>.x a new value ...

aRootUiWINDOW = Tk()                                    # .GUI <Tk()> context
aRootUiWINDOW.title(    'Web TkGUI... v0.0' )           # .SET w.[TITLE]
aRootUiWINDOW.geometry( '1200x600-50-50')               # .SET w.size ... 1200 x 600 [px] w.right-edge -50[px] left from screen-right, w.bottom-edge -50[px] up from screen-botton
aRootUiWINDOW.configure( background = 'black' )         # .SET w.bg
app = GuiApplication(    aRootUiWINDOW )                # .SET <app>
aRootUiWINDOW.lift()                                    # .SET visible
aRootUiWINDOW.mainloop()                                # .GUI controller
```

Comment: I agree with avoiding globals as well, I was just providing a quick solution to the question :)

Comment: Sorry, but in self.x in callback, what i shall put?

Comment: @user3597474 Kindly excuse that copy/paste residual error. <code-snippet> corrected.